# Xamarin Settings Designer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm working on IOS using Xamarin to restore some old android code. When trying to compile, there's a missing assembly error, pointing me towards this block of code:

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "11.0.0.0")]

internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase 
{...}
```

The error I get is as follow:

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name ApplicationSettingsBase does
>   not exist in the namespace System.Configuration. Are you missing an
>   assembly reference? (CS0234)

I get the feeling the problem lies within the "Microsoft.VisualStudio" part but I have no idea how to fix this.

**Edit** I see some people having similar problem being answered "Don't use Windows core dll". This might be the problem, but if it is I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Removing System.Configuration gave me a lot of additional errors but eventually fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this could work on Xamarin.Android but `System.Configuration` (both the assembly and the namespace) are **not** part of the mobile profile that are shipped with Xamarin.iOS (and Xamarin.Android).

Also, more specifically to Xamarin.iOS, there's no code generation possible (no JIT is allowed by Apple) so it does not include namespaces (or types) from `System.CodeDom.Compiler`